# calendar and date formatting error

Tags: ee2, calendar, date-format

No matter how I format my entry_date, it throws an error:

```
{exp:channel:calendar switch="calendarToday|calendarCell" channel="workshop_events" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="yes"}
{calendar_rows}
{if entries}
    {entries}
        {title}<br />
        {entry_date format="%g:%i%a"}
    {/entries}
{/if}
{/calendar_rows}
{/exp:channel:calendar}
```

PHP error on the entry_date is as follows:

> Undefined index: entry_date format="%g:%i%a"
>
> Filename: channel/mod.channel_calendar.php
>
> Line Number: 472

thanks for any advice.

Comment: output for the entry_date is the unformatted "1378055700"

Comment: not enough reputation to answer my question right now. but found out that this is a bug in EE 2.7.0

Answer (score 1):

why not use :

```
{exp:channel:calendar switch="calendarToday|calendarCell" channel="workshop_events" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="yes"}
{calendar_rows}
{if entries}
    {entries}
        {title}<br />
        {date format="%g:%i%a"}
    {/entries}
{/if}
{/calendar_rows}
{/exp:channel:calendar}
```

Comment: because I'm looking to display the entry_date, not the date.

Comment: ah OK, I thought that within an entries tag pair {date} would output the entry date

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in EE 2.7.0 (thanks @solspace for pointing that out [offline]).
meanwhile, I used PHP to solve this issue:

```
<?php echo date("g:i:a",{entry_date}); ?>
```

I also had to use date_default_timezone_set() because my server's settings were different than EE's general settings but it's working beautifully.